# HttpClient Post Request, and getting this error "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,"

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code to send the post request to API

```
string RequestUri = "api/MyProj/XYZ";
string uri = "http://stagingmyapp.xyz.com";
string ContentBody = "{\"DeviceType\":\"desktop\",\"matchesData\":[{\"MatchId\":988682,\"HomeTeamName\":\"Chelsea\",\"AwayTeamName\":\"Bayern Munchen\",\"BetTypeId\":2,\"BetValue\":null,\"OddEU\":\"3.85\",\"OddUK\":\"14/5\",\"Tip\":\"1\"}]}";
var requestToken = new HttpRequestMessage
{
Method = HttpMethod.Post,
RequestUri = new Uri(new Uri(uri), RequestUri),
Content = new StringContent(ContentBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
requestToken.Headers.Clear();
requestToken.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", SetTokenModel.Token));
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
var res = await client.SendAsync(requestToken);
}
```

and I'm getting this error "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1", even though if I pass the same ContentBody (JSON) directly to the request through Postman then I got the accurate result.
The same code is working fine for whole application(means for other post requests).
As you can see, I have passed the same `ContentBody` in Postman and I got the result, but in C# I'm getting error. If it is server side error then it should give me an error here in postman too.
[image: Postman Image]

Comment: Did you write the server? Can you debug it / look at the logs?

Comment: I have looked at the logs, and I got this....
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLTQ02CI1IHM", Request id "0HLTQ02CI1IHM:00000008": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Looks like your server is throwing a `NullReferenceException` somewhere, then. It's up to you to figure out where, and why!

Comment: Did you try with some other request format converting your `ContentBody` into `Json` format?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm converting the `ContentBody` into `Json` for each request... and worked fine...

Comment: @canton7, OK, for one more time I'm going to debug my app... then I'll let you that what happened...

Comment: Note that this problem is on the *server* -- your question only contains information about the client

Comment: Note that your request in Postman has some cookies, and way more headers

Comment: Please update your question with postman valid dummy data I will make it workable , I am pretty sure your request has problem.

Comment: Yes, two of them are as follows (1).Content-Type, (2).Authorization and I'm providing these headers and remaining 9 are temporary headers.

Comment: Maybe the server relies on them? Without knowing what's causing the NRE, it's impossible to say

Comment: Its very shocking to get screenshot from a developer for testing cases!